# Что лучше, выделить много памяти или много указателей на память?

Tags: графы, память, указатели, c++

Есть задача, нужно создать взвешенный граф в виде матрицы смежности. Нужен int-массив, который будет одновременно означать и связь и ее "цену". Ну так вот, весь прикол в том, что (в реале) не все элементы будут связаны друг с другом, а значит некоторый объем памяти лежать без дела => умнее будет создать массив указателей, и те элементы которые не используются будут = NULL, т.е. память занимать не будет...Но опять же я занимаю много памяти под адреса. Что же лучше? Вообще, указатели же имеет "вес"?

Comment: >Вообще, указатели же имеет "вес"?

Конечно имеет: `4` байта на архит-ре `x86` и `8` байт на архит-ре `x64`. По теме: выпишите для себя, какие операции будут проводиться с данным графом, "примерно" опишите алгоритмы, которые Вы для этого будете использовать. После этого можно "примерно" взвесить, какая скорость для тех или иных алгоритмов Вам потребуется. Если число алгоритмов, для которых скорость будет важнее будет больше, чем для остальных, можно закрывать глаза на некоторые издержки. Нет - значит надо искать компромисс, например: упаковывать/распаковывать граф по требованию, или порционно

Comment: т.е. сэкономить память не получиться? кроме как упаковки/распаковки...

Comment: >т.е. сэкономить память не получиться? кроме как упаковки/распаковки...

Я просто отмечаю взаимосвязь между "экономия памяти" и "скорость работы". Т.к. обход массива из косъвенных ссылок в общем случае - операция достаточно медлительная, т.к. требует чтения большего числа страниц памяти.  
 --  
А по объему памяти - Вы можете спокойно посчитать, насколько будет эффективнее хранить указатели: на x86 без дополнительных алгоритмов упаковки **выгоды не будет**. На x64 будет **проигрыш в 2 раза**.

Comment: @Djonny, а сколько у Вас элементов (вершин)?  И сколько (в среднем) связей у одной вершины?

Comment: Почему микрооптимизация? Вы уже уперлись в предел? Сделайте так, чтобы код как можно меньше зависел от точной стратегии выделения памяти, реализуйте как вам кажется удобнее, когда упрётесь в необходимость улучшений, тогда и будете улучшать.

Comment: @avp, количество вершин и связей - случайное число, варьируется от единиц до фантазии препода.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У Кнута в первом томе есть пример, как можно хранить такие матрицы, достаточно экономно и с возможностью быстро индексировать.

Для хранения одного элемента используется структура

```
struct Node {
  int row; // это и следующее поле можно и исключить
  int col; // ниже будет описана замена.
  Node * next;
  Node * bottom;
  Data data; // а это одно (или несколько  полей), где собственно хранятся данные.
}
```

Поэтому получается, что на каждый элемент нужно два дополнительных указателя (8-16 байт) и, возможно, ещё 4-8-16 байт для ускорения работы (и возможно отладки).

Индексы также не обязательно хранить в `int`. Вполне может оказаться, что short может оказаться достаточным.

Данные хранятся следующем виде. Каждая нода хранит ссылку на следующую ноду в строке и следующую ноду в столбце. Если в данной строке/столбце больше правее/ниже нет нод, то хранится ссылка на самую верхнюю/левую, то есть, зацикливаем.

Если данных 4 байта, и система 32 битная, то уже при заполнении менее, чем на треть, уже будет выигрыш.

**Как работать с такой матрицей**

Заводим один вектор, который будет хранить указатели на списки строк. Что бы найти какой-то элемент по индексу, нужно просто в векторе взять нужную строку, а потом просто пройтись по элементам до нахождения нужного. Если нужно посчитать сумму по строке - также не сложно - просто нужно получить строку и суммировать элементы. Нулевых нет, но они не меняют картины.

Но если размерности матрицы большие ( к примеру 100000 на 100000), то есть смысл просто сделать список всех существующий строк и столбцов.

**Подсуммировав все, получаем такое**

```
struct Node {
  int row; 
  int col; 
  Node * next;
  Node * bottom;
  Data data; // а это одно (или несколько  полей), где собственно хранятся данные.
}
std::list<Node*> rows;
std::list<Node*> cols;

// дальше алгоритмы словесные.
Node * get(int i, int j) {
   // Пройтись циклом по rows до нужной строки.
   // Если такой строки  нет, значит элемент нулевой
   // иначе проходим по строке (используя указатель next), ищем нужный элемент.
}

// Добавление элемента.
void add(Node * n) {

   // Находим нужную строку. Если строки в списке rows нет, нужно вставить.
   // добавляем этот элемент в эту строку.
   // если строка есть, то проходим циклом, что бы найти место вставки, 
   // поправляем два указателя
   // аналогичное проделываем с столбцами.
}
// удаление аналогично.
```

Возможно я немного модифицировал идею Кнута, поэтому настойчиво  рекомендую взять его книгу и поискать (думаю легко по заголовкам найдется, первый том).

Также в книге рекомендуется создать свой пул объектов, если предполагается, что данные будут часто модифицироваться.

Ещё раз напомню, данный алгоритм будет очень эффективным, если кол-во элементов значительно ( в сотни раз) меньше общей вместимости матрицы.

Comment: IMHO для указанных алгоритмов `bottom` в Node не нужен.

Если пустых строк мало, то для поиска строки можно добавить хэш. Или (если большинство строк заполнены) вообще использовать вектор строк.

Если некоторые элементы имеют аномально много связей, то для них тоже можно хэшировать список связей (т.е. строку).

--

Опять же вопрос к автору: какие у Вас данные (сколько элементов, среднее к-во связей одног элемента)?

Comment: я привел общую структуру. А уже по задаче можно подрезать-урезать.

Comment: Это правильно.

А вообще, я правильно понял, что `bottom` это список (кольцевой) всех нодов с одинаковым `col`?

Comment: да, правильно. Если нужно бегать и по столбцам, то они ещё как нужны. А в некоторых случаях может и двухсвязанные списки нужны. Но это уже особые задачи. У Кнута, насколько я помню, отсутствует списоки строк и столбцов, он там проблему индексации решает по другому. Но я сходу не помню.

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Обязательно почитаю Кнута. Только не совсем понятно что за bottom.

Comment: next - указатель на следующий (правый) элемент в *строке*, а bottom - на следующий (ниже) элемент в *столбце*.

Comment: @KoVadim, A! все, понял, пошел переваривать) Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Два стандартных представления связей в графе это 1) матрица, где элемент (i,j) указывает есть ли связь между i-ой и j-ой вершинами и 2) массив списков, где i-ый элемент массива содержит список связный с ним вершин. Если связи (i,j) в графе нет, то в i-ом списке не будет элемента j.

Оба подхода имеют плюсы и минусы. Плюс второго подхода в экономии памяти.

Comment: вопрос не об этом

Comment: >некоторый объем памяти лежать без дела => умнее будет создать массив указателей, и те элементы которые не используются будут = NULL, т.е. память занимать не будет...Но опять же я занимаю много памяти под адреса. Что же лучше?
Был дан ответ на вопрос "что же лучше" когда "некоторый объем памяти лежать без дела".

Comment: Если читать внимательнее, можно понять, что я имел ввиду 1 из 2 вариантов.

Comment: @Djonny, если Вы определенно хотите выбора между матрицей чисел и матрицей указателей на числа, то ответ очевиден:

**Матрица чисел.**

Более того, если все веса укладываются в 0..255 (или -128..127), то можно взять матрицу байт.

Еще меньший диапазон весов можно упаковать в еще более компактную матрицу из нескольких бит на элемент. 

(Надеюсь с битами работать умеете?)

Comment: А если изъясняться точнее, то можно получать ответы именно на те вопросы, которые имелись ввиду.

Comment: @forgbit, в общем, у меня нет смысла перед вами распинаться, просто в следующий раз, читайте, пожалуйста, вопрос внимательнее. Просто получается, что я спрашиваю про яйца, а вы мне про курицу.

Answer (score 1):

Это называется сильно разреженными матрицами, рассматривалось, к примеру, Кнутом. Есть давнишняя книжка Писанецки строго на эту тему

Answer (score 1):

Просто создайте указатель на указатель ;) **